# BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); returns null

Tags: android, bluetooth, initialization, adapter

I'm starting to develop an app to communicate with an arduino device through bluetooth.

I'm initializing the bt adapter with

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

The problem is that btAdapter returns null,

```
txt_status.append("\nAdapter " + btAdapter);
```

Its like the device hasn't got a bluetooth adapter, which is not my case.

Any ideas? I'm searching around with no luck.

Thanks, Federico

Complete code of the activity:

```
package com.voice.benz.instaurentremote;

import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.Set;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
public class bluetooth extends ActionBarActivity {


    private TextView bluetoothPaired;
    private TextView txt_status;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    private ListView listview_devices;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> dispositivi;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
    private static final int BLUETOOTH_ON=1000;

    private TextView txt_bluetoothStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

        txt_bluetoothStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_bluetooth_status);
        txt_status          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_status);

        listview_devices    = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_devices);
        adapter             = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        listview_devices.setAdapter(adapter);


        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        if (btAdapter == null)
        {
            System.out.println ("Bluetooth non supportato");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("Bluetooth inizializzato");
        }

        if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            // Il bluetooth è già attivato

            String mydeviceaddress = btAdapter.getAddress();
            String mydevicename = btAdapter.getName();

            String status = mydevicename + " : " + mydeviceaddress;
            txt_bluetoothStatus.setText(status);

        }
        else
        {
            // Attiva bluetooth
        }



    }

    public void attivaBluetooth (View view) {

        if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOn, BLUETOOTH_ON);
        }
        //else
            //load();


    }

    public void disattivaBluetooth (View view)
    {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            btAdapter.disable();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==BLUETOOTH_ON && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            load();
        }
    }
    private void load()
    {
        dispositivi = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        adapter.clear();
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : dispositivi)
            adapter.add(bt.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bluetooth, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the app manifest I've added this two lines 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

Comment: Is BlueTooth enabled on your device? It seems to be the same with network interfaces, where only activated and connected devices (WiFi or cellular) are returned and `null` if none are enabled.

Comment: Yes, it's activated. By the way using this code:
    String mydeviceaddress = btAdapter.getAddress();
    String mydevicename = btAdapter.getName();
it returns my bluetooth address and mac code, so it's working.

The real problem is that this code:
      if (!btAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOn, BLUETOOTH_ON);
        }

returns a exception (nullpointer), i'm investigating on the cause

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or any real device?

Comment: Real device..I've tested the app on two devices with the same result, something must be wrong

Comment: Can you post your complete activity code in which you are getting NULL exception ?

Comment: I've edited the post with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your code line,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

with

```
btAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

its all about local variable and Class level variable.

You are getting Bluetooth adapter in onCreate as local variable and accessing outside of `onCreate()` the class level variable which is not initialized and always remain null.