# getDefaultAdapter() method is not supported when i am using this code

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-emulator

When I am using this code getDefaultAdapter couldn't supported and [image]showing  toast also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062616/bluetoothadapter-getdefaultadapter-returns-null).
You can try something like

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
```

Answer (score 0):

`getDefaultAdapter()` will work, but they are recommending you migrate to use BluetoothManager and `getAdapter()`.

In an Activity:

```
val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
m_bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
```

In a Fragment:

```
val bluetoothManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
m_bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
```

There is no `toast()` function. It apparently was provided by the `core-ktx` Jetpack library at one time and later removed. Use the [standard way](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts) of showing Toasts.